# "update in-place" runs indefinitely in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I would like to apply "Azure Services" if there is no value through the conditional statement below, and "var.network_rules_bypass" if there is a value. By the way, Terraform keeps trying to update, whether it has a value or not, as shown below. I'm asking for your help.

- Problem
  If you apply "terraform plan -> terraform apply" and try "terraform plan" again, you will continue to update.

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
        id                                = "/subscriptions/000000000-0000000...."
        name                              = "teststorage"
        tags                              = {
            "Environment" = "prd"
        }
        # (32 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ network_rules {
          ~ default_action             = "Allow" -> "Deny"
            # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

- main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
  name                     = var.azstorageaccount_name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.account_replication_type
  account_kind             = var.account_kind
  access_tier              = var.access_tier
  large_file_share_enabled = var.large_file_share_enabled
  is_hns_enabled           = var.is_hns_enabled
  sftp_enabled          = var.is_sftp_enabled
  public_network_access_enabled     = var.public_network_access_enabled

  blob_properties  {
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = var.container_delete_retention_policy
    }
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = var.delete_retention_policy
    }
  }

  dynamic "network_rules" {
    for_each = var.network_rules_enabled ? ["true"] : []
    content {
      default_action             = var.network_rules_default_action
      ip_rules                   = var.network_rules_ip_rules
      virtual_network_subnet_ids = var.network_rules_virtual_network_subnet_ids
      bypass                     = var.network_rules_bypass != [] ? var.network_rules_bypass : ["AzureServices"] <==== This!!!!
      dynamic "private_link_access" {
        for_each = var.private_link_access
        content {
          endpoint_resource_id = private_link_access.value.endpoint_resource_id
          endpoint_tenant_id   = private_link_access.value.endpoint_tenant_id
        }
      }
    }
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.tag}"
  }
}
```

- var.tf

```
variable "system_rg" {
  description = "The Prefix used for all resources in this example"
  type        = string
  default     = "testrg"
}

variable "tag" {
  type    = string
  default = "prd"
}

variable "azstorageaccount_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "teststg001"
}

variable "large_file_share_enabled" {
  type    = string
  default = "false"
}

variable "account_tier" {
  type = string
  default = "Standard"
}

variable "account_replication_type" {
  type = string
  default = "LRS"
}

variable "account_kind" {
  type = string
  default = "StorageV2"
}

variable "access_tier" {
  type = string
  default = "Hot"
}

variable "is_hns_enabled" {
  type = string
  default = "false"
}

variable "is_sftp_enabled" {
  type = string
  default = "false"
}

variable "public_network_access_enabled" {
  type    = string
  default = "true"
}

variable "container_delete_retention_policy" {
  type    = string
  default = "7"
}

variable "delete_retention_policy" {
  type    = string
  default = "7"
}

variable "network_rules_enabled" {
  description = "Boolean to enable Network Rules on the Storage Account, requires `network_bypass`, `allowed_cidrs`, `subnet_ids` or `default_firewall_action` correctly set if enabled."
  type        = bool
  default     = true # true
}

variable "network_rules_default_action" {
  type = string
  default = "Deny" # Allow
}

variable "network_rules_ip_rules" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [ "10.10.10.10 ]
}

variable "network_rules_virtual_network_subnet_ids" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [ "/subscriptions/.../" ]
}

variable "network_rules_bypass" {
  type = list(string)
  # default = [ "Logging", "Metrics", "AzureServices" ]
  default = []
}

variable "private_link_access" {
  description = "List of Privatelink objects to allow access from."
  type = list(object({
    endpoint_resource_id = string
    endpoint_tenant_id = optional(string, null)
  }))
  default = [ 
    { 
      endpoint_resource_id = "/subscriptions/00000-0000-00000-000000/providers/Microsoft.Security/datascanners/storageDataScanner"
      endpoint_tenant_id = null
    },
    # { 
    #   endpoint_resource_id = 
    #   endpoint_tenant_id = 
    # }
  ]
  nullable = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem If you apply "terraform plan -> terraform apply" and try "terraform plan" again, you will continue to update.

The reason for `Terraform` updating the network rules is the `bypass` argument within the `azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.network_rules` block. These cause `Terraform` to **plan** and **apply** a change to the resource, even when there are no changes in values.

[image]

To resolve the issue, you can use the `ignore_changes` **lifecycle block** within the `azurerm_storage_account` block.

Here is the updated code to prevent updates.

```json
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name = "existing-resource-group-name"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
      name                = "example-vnet"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
      name                 = "example-subnet"
      resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
      service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
      name                     = var.azstorageaccount_name
      resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      account_tier             = var.account_tier
      account_replication_type = var.account_replication_type
      account_kind             = var.account_kind
      access_tier              = var.access_tier
      large_file_share_enabled = var.large_file_share_enabled
      is_hns_enabled           = var.is_hns_enabled
      sftp_enabled             = var.is_sftp_enabled
      public_network_access_enabled = var.public_network_access_enabled
    
      blob_properties  {
        container_delete_retention_policy {
          days = var.container_delete_retention_policy
        }
        delete_retention_policy {
          days = var.delete_retention_policy
        }
      }
    
      dynamic "network_rules" {
        for_each = var.network_rules_enabled ? ["true"] : []
        content {
          default_action             = var.network_rules_default_action
          ip_rules                   = var.network_rules_ip_rules
          virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
          bypass                     = coalesce(var.network_rules_bypass, ["AzureServices"])
        }
      }
      tags = {
        Environment = "${var.tag}"
      }
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [
          network_rules,
        ]
      }
    }
```

After adding the `ignore_changes`, when I try to `terraform plan`, it's not updating the resource as below.

[image]

Reference: [How and when to ignore lifecycle changes in Terraform](https://itnext.io/how-and-when-to-ignore-lifecycle-changes-in-terraform-ed5bfb46e7ae)